# Add pear/xml_parser to compser.json

Tags: php, composer-php, pear

I'm trying to include pear/xml_serializer in my *Laravel* project. So, in the composer.json file I do

```
"repositories": {
    "phppear": {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    }
},
```

To load the repo, and then I include it in the require section like this:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "pear/xml_serializer": "dev-master"
},
```

And that works fine. The issue is that this package requires pear/xml_parser, but doing

```
"require": {
    ...
    "pear/xml_parser": "dev-master",
    "pear/xml_serializer": "dev-master"
},
```

Doesn't work. Neither does xml_parser2. I get this error:

```
The requested package pear/xml_parser2 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

I have to assume that means it can't find the package, but I can't figure out how to load it. I've tried several different variations of the commands above. The packages are here:

http://pear.php.net/package/xml_serializer
http://pear.php.net/package/xml_parser2

But only the first one can be found? Do I need to get the xml_parser from somewhere else?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
{
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.php.net/xml_parser": "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/xml_serializer": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ]
}
```

Results in:

```
 ...
  - Installing pear-pear.php.net/xml_parser (1.3.4)
  - Installing pear-pear.php.net/xml_serializer (0.20.2)
```